# Como Bloquear el boton atras virtual en dispositivo android React Native

Tags: react-native

Estoy siguiendo un curso de React Native y he llegado a algo de las escenas, mi problema es que tengo la primer scena login y una segunda de muestra de datos y quisiera poder quitar o evitar que el usuario pueda regresar al login al momento de estar en la segunda, como podria evitar eso? había pensando que al momento que la presione cierre la aplicación o no se que me recomendarían 
Codigo que tengo es este:

```
<Router sceneStyle={{margin: 0}} hideNavBar>
        <Scene>
            <Scene key="auth" hideNavBar>
                <Scene  hideNavBar={false} key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Inicie Sesion" initial/>
            </Scene>
            <Scene key="main" hideNavBar>
                <Scene
                    panHandlers={null}
                    gesturesEnabled={false}
                    onRight={() => BackHandler.exitApp()}
                    rightTitle="Add"
                    hideNavBar={false}
                    key="employedList" 
                    component={EmployeeList} 
                    title="Empleados" 
                />
            </Scene>
        </Scene>
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo agrego estas dentro de la Scene  con eso se bloquea :D espero te sirva

```
<Scene
    key='HomePage'
    title='Menú Principal'
    gestureEnabled={false}
    panHandlers={null}
    back={true}/>
```